# Custom Facebook page tab does not show anything

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a custom tab from my app in facebook and I've add it to my facebook page. But, although I see in the debugger that there is a request (HTTP POST) made to my page which returns a response (the html I want to display), **nothing is shown in the tab itself and the iframe stays empty**.

Is there anything special the html should return? Anybody faced that issue?

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: There is none :(

Comment: Can you show the issue live? (You will need to set your app & page public so that we can see it.)

Comment: @CBroe

Sure here is the page : https://www.facebook.com/bReputationcom/app/213417752407290/

The custom tab is the last one "Avis sur B-Reputation"

The url is : https://b-reputation.com/fr/public/811565829

Comment: Ah ! There is this error "https://b-reputation.com/fr/public/811565829 does not permit cross-origin framing." So I need to allow cross origin POST on that page? Is there a security concern doing this ?

Comment: Your system sends the header `X-Frame-Options: Sameorigin`, and that tells the browser that this page is only allowed to be embedded in (i)frames on the same domain. You need to remove that. (`Allow-From` to specify other domains that are allowed to frame the page exists, but browser support is not good enough yet, Chrome doesn't support it.)

Comment: It works! Thanks @CBroe. I had to add to my nodejs server only for that route :  `res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com');`

Comment: Have you checked that in all relevant browsers? http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-frame-options Basically all the webkit-based browsers do not seem to support ALLOW-FROM yet. (I don’t know how they handle this - whether they allow it despite it, or reject it even if the iframe was located on the specified domain.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CBroe. I had to add to my nodejs server only for that route : res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com');